# Is there an English word for the fruit we call paterna in El Salvador?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

Can someone name the fruit in the pictures?

[image: Picture of a long green fruit split open]  [image: Picture of a long green fruit]

Here in El Salvador we call it *paterna* but if I literally translate it  means something related to *father* as in *paternal X* obviously it's not what I'm looking for. So if someone knows the name of it please be kind enough to share it with me.

Comment: I've never seen anything like it. It is possible that there is no English name for it.

Comment: A little searching suggests that the *fruta paterna* is also called *guama*, *guaba*, or *inga*.  We don't seem to have a common name for it, so it looks like it's just called by its scientific name, [Inga edulis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inga_edulis).

Comment: I did find some references to [inga bean](http://www.edible.co.nz/fruits.php?fruitid=35_Inga%20Bean), [inga fruit](http://www.indigenous-rainforest-keepers.com/the-inga-plant-family.html), and even "[ice cream bean](http://www.daleysfruit.com.au/fruit%20pages/icecream.htm)"!

Comment: I agree this is not guava or guaba. However I've found the name guama to be useful when referring to this fruit. Although I still have doubts about how should I refer to it when talking to an English speaker.

Comment: I don't think this fruit is same as inga tho. Inga sounds african to me lol

Comment: There is no English word that I have found...I love paternas I eat them all the time with lime salt and hot sauce!

Comment: It looks like (but a lil bit different from) 'petai' in my native language. I Googled it; I found a 'bitter bean'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about this, but Wikipedia refers to this fruit as the "Inga". This is a little-known fruit (I'm assuming), so you'll probably not need to use this fruit much. When talking to anyone, just call it an 'Inga' or 'Inga fruit'.

Hope this helps, and good luck with your English!

Comment: Well I think I'll just call it inga then.

Comment: There's another name for it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inga_feuillei

Comment: I think I changed my mind I'm just going to call it "paterna" because I was talking to my father and he said that: paleto, guama, inga and pepeto are different than paterna and that there are many more fruits that look like paterna but they aren't so I'm just calling it paterna.

Comment: @ManuelHernandez I think that is a good idea. If you said "My favorite fruit is called paterna." I would just assume there was no English word for it and say "I've never heard of that one - what does it taste like?" There are many instances of plants keeping their names from their native country, like [Rambutan](http://www.shutterstock.com/s/rambutan/search.html) for example.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is commonly called **[Ice cream bean fruit](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=ice%20cream%20bean%20fruit&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7loWrtendAhVbFYgKHZ3XBKcQ_AUIDigB&biw=1920&bih=978&safe=active&ssui=on)**.

Comment: Brenda, can you cite a source to make this a better answer?

Comment: @Brenda, I added a Google search result link, but please feel free to edit the link/source.